# Error starting gulpfile.js

Tags: gulp

I collect test gulpfile.js When I run the "gulp js:build" command in the console, I get an error. Who knows how to fix it? Where can I find these files?

```
    gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.js) 
        .pipe(rigger()) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
        .pipe(uglify()) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js)) 
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); 
});

Console Error:

gulp js:build                                                                
[23:40:03] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\test_build\gulpfile.js                   
[23:40:03] Starting 'js:build'...                                              
[23:40:03] Finished 'js:build' after 10 ms                                     
buffer.js:207                                                                  
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(                                            
    ^                                                                          

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string
, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined    

at Function.from (buffer.js:207:11)
at new Buffer (buffer.js:182:17)
at C:\Users\м\Documents\test_build\node_modules\gulp-rigger\index.js:20:29
at Rigger.<anonymous> (C:\Users\м\Documents\test_build\node_modules\rigger\index.js:719:9)
at Rigger.emit (events.js:182:13)
at C:\Users\м\Documents\test_build\node_modules\rigger\index.js:252:16
at C:\Users\м\Documents\test_build\node_modules\rigger\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:232:13
at C:\Users\м\Documents\test_build\node_modules\rigger\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:113:21
at C:\Users\м\Documents\test_build\node_modules\rigger\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:24:16
at C:\Users\м\Documents\test_build\node_modules\rigger\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:229:17
```